# Bone constraint rotation not working correctly

Tags: bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics, axis

I am following a skeleton rig tutorial on youtube step by step and despite having the exact same setup, my armature behaves incorrectly. https://youtu.be/jp_SqjB0468?t=920 at minute 15:40.
This is the result I am supposed to be getting:

[image: expected Z axis rotation of the foot using the IK bone]

This is the result I am getting, the foot seems to rotate around its own local Z axis and not the parent's, even though the "Copy rotation" Space is set to "Local With Parent":

[image: actual Z axis rotation of the foot using the IK bone]

This is my constraint setup:

[image: copy rotation from the IK bone constraint set to space: local with parent both sides]

I am struggling to find the error. Can this be a potential glitch in blender 2.8? I remember giving this tutorial a try in 2.79 and I can't recall having this problem.

UPDATE:
I confirmed that this is caused by version 2.8. I created an identical armature in version 2.79b where it rotated correctly. When I opened the exact same file in 2.8, the bones rotated differently. I will follow a different step by step tutorial made in 2.8 and see if I can find what has changed in 2.8 that's affecting this.

FINAL UPDATE:
"Relationship - Child of" constraint used instead of "Transform - Copy rotation" has solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I'm not sure about this method, I think it works on the video because his foot is almost aligned to his controller on every axis, that's a solution by the way, but if they are not aligned, it will be ok as long as you rotate the controller on the X axis (because both bones are aligned on this axis), but, as soon as you rotate the controller on its Y axis or Z axis, the foot will go crazy (because you ask it to rotate on its own Y and Z and that's what it gives).

In my opinion the solution is to parent the foot to the controller.This way, the foot follows the controller no matter what. Then, if you want to make sure that the foot bone will stick to the shin bone, you can give it a *Copy Location* with *Space* > *Pose Space* and a *Head/Tail* value of 1.

Comment: Thank you. I did some testing, and the issue really is caused by 2.8 doing "things" differently from 2.79. The exact same bone rotates around global Z axis in 2.79 but local Z axis in 2.8. (I checked the file I saved with Blender 2.79 in 2.8 and the behaviour has changed.)

Comment: You were right. I used "Relationship - Child of" constraint and it works just as I needed. Thanks again.